# Triviality of tangent bundle of complex sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles

Considering the complex sphere
 $$S_\mathbb{C}^{n-1} = \left\{ z \in \mathbb{C}^n  |  \sum_{i=1}^n |z_i|^2 =1 \right\}$$ 
 and its associated tangent bundle $T S_\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$, can one find a section?

I think I understand that in the real case, $\mathbb{S}_{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the tangent bundle is trivial for $n=1,2,4,8$.

Is that right? Can one give a similar result for the complex sphere?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by a complex sphere?

Comment: Edited original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z_i = x_i + iy_i$, then $|z_i|^2 = x_i^2 + y_i^2$, so

\begin{align*}
S^{n-1}_{\mathbb{C}} &= \left\{(z_1, \dots, z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n \mid \sum_{i=1}^n|z_i|^2 = 1\right\}\\ 
&= \left\{(x_1, \dots, x_n, y_1, \dots, y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{2n} \mid \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 + y_i^2 = 1\right\}\\
&= S^{2n-1}.
\end{align*}

So $TS^{n-1}_{\mathbb{C}} = TS^{2n-1}$ which is trivial if and only if $n = 1, 2, 4$. However, for any value of $n$, $TS^{n-1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ admits at least one nowhere-zero section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand, apart from the last sentence. Doesn’t the existence of a nowhere-zero section imply bundle triviality?

Comment: @user288227: No. A rank $k$ vector bundle is trivial if and only if it admits $k$ linearly independent sections.

Comment: Actually, there is a subtlety: the tangent space of the complex sphere is intended as the hyperplane that is orthogonal to the element in the sense of the hermitian inner product, which is not the same as the tangent space in the real sense... Is that question well-defined within the framework of tangent bundles? @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: That's not the tangent space, its only a subspace of the tangent space. What you're describing is a complex rank $n - 1$ vector bundle $E$ on $S^{n-1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ with the property that $TS^{n-1}_{\mathbb{C}} = E\oplus\varepsilon^1$ as real bundles where $\varepsilon^1$ is the trivial real line bundle. Note that $E$ need not admit a section.

Comment: Indeed, it’s not the tangent bundle. Sorry, I am unfamiliar with this  topic.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. The question I had in mind would be perhaps better expressed in that way: Is the complex sphere $S^{n-1}_\mathbb{C}$ parallelizable, i.e. can one find a continuous map $\phi$ from the sphere onto the unitary group $\mathcal{U}(n)$, so that the first column of $\phi(z)$ is equal to $z$?

Comment: For example, in dimension 2, such a map exists, e.g. $$ \begin{pmatrix} z_1\\z_2 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}z_1 & -z_2^* \\ z_2 & z_1^* \end{pmatrix}$$  Does it exist in dimension 3 ?

Comment: If there were such a map, the bundle $E$ that I mentioned in my previous comment would be trivial and hence $TS^{n-1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ would be trivial. But $TS^{n-1}_{\mathbb{C}} = TS^{2n-1}$ is only trivial for $n = 1, 2, 4$, so such a map can only exist in these dimensions. You wrote down the map for $n = 2$. It turns out that there is no such map for $n = 4$, but the proof for this is complicated.